# How to set up nested IFS in google sheets when working with DURATION

Tags: time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been asked to set up a Google Sheet for a billing department with the following requirements

Inputs

- Start Time
- End Time

These will be formatted using TIME

The Request is to take the duration output (End Time-Start Time) and make"Billable Time" by automatically appling these rules

1. If Duration is less than 60 minutes, then set Billable Time to 60 minutes
2. If Duration is more than 60 minutes, but less than 90 minutes, then set Billable Time to 90 minutes
3. If Duration is more than 90 minutes, then set Billable Time to the nearest quarter hour (15 minutes) rounding up.

My Current Formula is: `=IF(AND(TIME(1,0,0)>=(C2-B2),TIME(1,0,0),IF(AND(TIME(1,30,0)>=(C2-B2),TIME(1,30,0),IF(AND(TIME(1,30,0)>(C2-B2),CEILING(C2-B2,TIME(0,15,0))))))))`

Where B2 is the Start Time and C2 is the End Time

But I get the error

> Error
>   Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 1 arguments.

I've had some success with this formula but I can't seem to get the time values to work

`=IFS(value(C2-B2)=0," ",value(C2-B2)<=60,"60",value(C2-B2)<=90,"90",value(C2-B2)>90,ceiling(C2-B2,"00:15"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(C2-B2<=0.04166666667, 0.04166666667,
 IF(C2-B2<=0.0625, 0.0625,
 IF(C2-B2>0.0625, CEILING(C2-B2, 0.01041666667))))
```

[image]

**note:** all 3 cells formatted as **`TIME`**

### _______________________________________________________________

```
=IF(C2-B2<=0.04166666667, TEXT(0.04166666667, "hh:mm"),
 IF(C2-B2<=0.0625, TEXT(0.0625, "hh:mm"),
 IF(C2-B2>0.0625, TEXT(CEILING(C2-B2, 0.01041666667), "hh:mm"))))
```

[image]

**note:** all 3 cells formatted as **`AUTOMATIC`**

[image]

Comment: Formatting the cells as TIME was much more useful. Thank you so much for your quick reply!